# write data to an unexposed ble handler

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to communicate with a device via BLE.
It has a mobile application that uses BLE to control it. I extracted the btsnoop logs from my mobile.

and I see that the data is sent to the handler 0x10. But I don't see that handler when I'm connected to the device with the bleak library (python). I tried sending some of the packets I have seen to all the handlers exposed to me and non of them had any effect.

I have read that the device might not send all its available handlers.
because I already know the handler I have tried just sending it to that packet but the library raises an exception.

is there any other way (preferably with some Python library) to send data to an unexposed handler?

Comment: A great way to start is to connect to the BLE device using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile). This often allows you to find the needed characteristic and also allows you to send some test commands to the device. Keep in mind that some manufacturers use encryption or other techniques to essentially only allow their own app to communicate with their devices. This might hinder you to use your own.